# Commerce Server error when running catalog export service

Tags: microsoft-commerce-server, commerceserver2007

```
System.ArgumentException: '_', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character.
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.InvalidXmlChar(Int32 ch, Char* pDst, Boolean entitize)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteElementTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at Microsoft.CommerceServer.Catalog.Internal.XmlErrorsBase.GetExternalError(Int32     lineNumber, String errorMessage)
   at Microsoft.CommerceServer.Catalog.Internal.XmlErrorsBase.GetExternalError(String errorMessage)
   at Microsoft.CommerceServer.Internal.CatalogExport.Export(Object obj)
   at Microsoft.CommerceServer.Internal.CatalogExport.Export(Guid operationId)
   at Microsoft.CommerceServer.Catalog.Internal.CatalogExportService.Export(ExportOptions exportOptions, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.CommerceServer.Catalog.Internal.CatalogExportService.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

It looks like the catalog export fails, then it fails again trying to write the error message.  It *looks* like bad data, but we can't find anything. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried exporting the catalog using the Catalog manager? The log would tell you where the bad data is, or at least it would give you a clue.

I agree it looks like bad data, do you have multiple languages in your catalog?